# HTTP Status 404 – Not Found - com Spring, HIbernate, Jpa, Mysql eTomcat

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, jpa, tomcat

Fiz uma alteração no meu projeto passando a responsabilidade para o Spring controlar as transações conforme documentação da Caelum e outros exemplos que busquei na web, ja busquei informações no google, livros, tutorais, etc... aparentemente o projeto está correto, porém por alguma motivo ele não consegue achar as classes mapeadas, a acaba trazendo uma pagina de erro 404, conforme imagem:enter image description here

a seguir minhas configurações web.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
    <display-name>projetoLoja</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>                
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>spring mvc</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>classpath:applicationContext.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
         <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring mvc</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
    </session-config>  
    <filter>
         <filter-name>SetCharacterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
         <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
         <init-param>
             <param-name>encoding</param-name>
             <param-value>UTF8</param-value>
         </init-param>
         <init-param>
             <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
             <param-value>true</param-value>
         </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>SetCharacterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>  

</web-app>
```

meu arquivo applicationContext.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
        xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
                            ">

    <context:component-scan base-package="br.com.loja.projetoloja" />
    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <mvc:default-servlet-handler/>    
    <mvc:interceptors>
        <bean class="br.com.loja.projetoloja.interceptor.AutorizadorInterceptor"></bean>
    </mvc:interceptors>
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
        <!-- <property name="exposeContext" value="true"/> -->
    </bean>


    <bean id="mysqlDataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>

        <!-- local --> 
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/banco?autoReconnect=true"/>
        <property name="username" value="root"/>
        <property name="password" value="xxxxx"/>
        <property name="validationQuery" value="SELECT 1"/>
        <property name="testOnBorrow" value="true"/>

    </bean> 

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="mysql" />
        <property name="dataSource" ref="mysqlDataSource" />        
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter"/>
        </property>
    </bean>  

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
    </bean>  

    <tx:annotation-driven />

</beans>
```

meu arquivo persistence.xml:

http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0">

```
<persistence-unit name="mysql" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">

    <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>

    <class>br.com.loja.projetoloja.modelo.Contato</class>
    <class>br.com.loja.projetoloja.modelo.Usuario</class>
    <class>br.com.loja.projetoloja.modelo.Veiculo</class>
    <class>br.com.loja.projetoloja.modelo.Pessoa</class>
    <class>br.com.loja.projetoloja.modelo.Marca</class>
    <class>br.com.loja.projetoloja.modelo.Modelo</class>
    <class>br.com.loja.projetoloja.modelo.Versao</class>
    <class>br.com.loja.projetoloja.modelo.Venda</class>
    <class>br.com.loja.projetoloja.modelo.Compra</class>
    <class>br.com.loja.projetoloja.modelo.Contasapagar</class>
    <class>br.com.loja.projetoloja.modelo.Logs</class>
    <class>br.com.loja.projetoloja.modelo.ContasPagasePagar</class>

    <properties>                    
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect"/>                                                           
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
        <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />                                                           
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

erro no console:

> 2020-03-09 08:56:08 DEBUG DispatcherServlet:863 - DispatcherServlet
>   with name 'spring mvc' processing GET request for
>   [/projetoLoja/listapessoas] 2020-03-09 08:56:08 DEBUG
>   RequestMappingHandlerMapping:301 - Looking up handler method for path
>   /listapessoas 2020-03-09 08:56:08 DEBUG
>   RequestMappingHandlerMapping:311 - Did not find handler method for
>   [/listapessoas] 2020-03-09 08:56:08 DEBUG SimpleUrlHandlerMapping:191
>   - Matching patterns for request [/listapessoas] are [/**] 2020-03-09 08:56:08 DEBUG SimpleUrlHandlerMapping:220 - URI Template variables
>   for request [/listapessoas] are {} 2020-03-09 08:56:08 DEBUG
>   SimpleUrlHandlerMapping:141 - Mapping [/listapessoas] to
>   HandlerExecutionChain with handler
>   [org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.DefaultServletHttpRequestHandler@35646544]
>   and 1 interceptor 2020-03-09 08:56:08 DEBUG DispatcherServlet:949 -
>   Last-Modified value for [/projetoLoja/listapessoas] is: -1 2020-03-09
>   08:56:08 DEBUG DispatcherServlet:1036 - Null ModelAndView returned to
>   DispatcherServlet with name 'spring mvc': assuming HandlerAdapter
>   completed request handling 2020-03-09 08:56:08 DEBUG
>   DispatcherServlet:997 - Successfully completed request

exemplo de um trecho de uma classe controller:

```
@Transactional
@Controller
public class PessoaController  extends HttpServlet{

    @Autowired
    PessoaDaoI daopessoa;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/listapessoas", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String lista(Model model) {
        //PessoaDao dao = new PessoaDao();
        model.addAttribute("pessoas", daopessoa.lista());
        //model.addAttribute("pessoas", dao.listaPessoas());
        return "listapessoas";
    }
```

Segue uma arquitetura das pastas:

enter image description here

Espero ter sido claro nas colocações, espero muito uma ajuda dos senhores!!

Answer (score 0):

Boa noite, apos muito custo rss (ja fazia dias) consegui resolver... e era uma alteração muito boba.

trocar

```
public class PessoaController extends HttpServlet{
```

por

```
public class PessoaController{
```